# Некоторая защита на сайт

Tags: javascript

Подскажите пожалуйста как сделать такие вещи и, возможно их вообще сделать:

1.Как закрыть пользователю Исходный код.

2.Как заблокировать URL строку (чтоб пользователь не мог ее изменить)

Comment: url строка - это там где пользователь вводит адрес?

Comment: От чего это защита ? от тараканов в голове разработчика ?

Answer (score 5):

Заблокировать просмотр исходного кода, как и изменение юрл нельзя.

Answer (score 2):

<body oncontextmenu="return false;"> - запрет на вызов контекстного меню (клик правой кнопкой мыши)

Answer (score 2):

Судя по всему, третий вопрос будет: "Как заблокировать запуск диспетчера задач, редактора реестра, а также загрузку в безопасном режиме и клавиатуру с мышью."

Признайтесь, вы Trojan.winlock пишете? Шучу-шучу.

Но скажите честно, зачем вам блокировать URL-строку?

По сабжу: можно конечно изощренно запретить правый клик (посмотреть пример можно [тут](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex9/noright.htm)), но самой проблемы это не решит. В Опере есть, например, магическое сочетание CTRL+U.

[upd] Ну и вдогонку. Немного помучав гугл, имеем следующие варианты:

1. Зашифровать. Лучший вариант из
       доступных. Можно написать шифратор
       самому или взять готовый.
2. Заблокировать правый клик. Проблемы
           не решит вообще, но получите
           моральное удовлетворение.
3. Не лезть в интернет. Хех.

Comment: Мне иногда кажется, что именно по той причине, что опера так легко разблокирует правую кнопку или плюет на некоторые "стандарты", ее недолюбливают:). Но обычные пользователи любят.

Comment: Либо ctr+s и во многих браузерах вам предложат выбрать папку, куда сохранить страницу)

Answer (score 0):

Исходный код того, что вы уже отправили пользователю(HTML/Javascript) скрыть нельзя.

Comment: Я видел как то на сайтах, что когда тыкаешь на правую клавишу мыши то тебе это действие запрещают..

Comment: ничего не запрещают. Никто не может мне запретить нажать правую кнопку мышки (ну разве она просто будет отсутствовать или рядом будет стоять суровый дядя с дубинкой).

Comment: >>>Я видел как то на сайтах, что когда тыкаешь на правую клавишу мыши то тебе это действие запрещают.>>>    
  
Свойства/Веб-разработка/исходный код страницы   
в Firefox. Так что не прокатит.  
Можно сделать компрессию JS. Тогда в исходном коде копаться не будут.

Answer (score 0):

Строку можно запретить изменять, если создать новое окно с помощью javascript метода [window.open('URL страници', '_blank', 'location=no')](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp). Правда URL может быть или не редактируемый, или вообще может не оказаться адресной строки - зависит от браузера.

Comment: что то вроде этого: 

<a href=javascript: onClick=window.open('URL страници', '_blank', 'location=no')> ?

Comment: Да. Только <a href=javascript: window.open('URL страници', '_blank', 'location=no')>
или уже на onClick поставьте. Но не все вместе в одном атрибуте.